# Disable number input in a text input with js

Tags: javascript, html

What I have to do is not permit to introduce number characters in a text input in a form, but I've to do it with javascript. Here's my HTML code:

```
<form id="formu">
<input type="text" id="num" />
</form>
```

And here's my JS code:

```
function numero(theEvent){

    var evento=theEvent||window.event;

        switch(evento.type){
            case 'keypress':
                if(document.getElementById("num").evento.keyCode>=48&&document.getElementById("num").evento.keyCode<=57){
                    return false;
                }
        }
    }
```

Comment: where did u call numero(theEvent) ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the new pattern attrib HTML ,

```
<input type="text" id="num" pattern="[A-Za-z]" title="Only Alphabets">
```

Answer (score 3):

```
function validateKeyStrokes(event) {
    var charCode = (event.which) ? event.which : event.keyCode;
    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}


<form id="formu">
<input type="text" id="num"  onkeypress="return validateKeyStrokes(event)" />
</form>
```

Try this

Answer (score 0):

Try using jQuery and a plugin for input text field filtering

[See here](http://www.thimbleopensource.com/tutorials-snippets/jquery-plugin-filter-text-input)

Comment: Why to use such a big library just to validate keystrokes?

Comment: It might be overkill indeed in some cases. On the other hand jQuery makes life easier with many common tasks which may justify using it. I've also thought about keypress event but it would not handle paste.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the HTML5 new input type number :

```
<input type="number" name="num" id="num">
```

But use with care if you want to provide old browsers support ...